# AWS CodeBuild Unzipped size must be smaller than 350198 bytes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, devops, aws-codebuild

I am trying to deploy and update code in multiple lambdas at the same time, but when making a push to my branch and deploying CodeBuild, I getting the following error:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the
> UpdateFunctionCode operation: Unzipped size must be smaller than
> 350198 bytes
>
> [Container] 2021/04/24 00:09:31 Command did not exit successfully aws
> lambda update-function-code --function-name my_lambda_03 --zip-file
> fileb://my_lambda_03.zip exit status 254 [Container] 2021/04/24
> 00:09:31 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED [Container]
> 2021/04/24 00:09:31 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR
> Message: Error while executing command: aws lambda
> update-function-code --function-name my_lambda_03 --zip-file
> fileb://my_lambda_03.zip. Reason: exit status 254

This is the **buildspec.yml**:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.x
    commands:
      - echo "Installing dependencies..."
  build:
    commands:
      - echo "Zipping all my functions....."
      - cd my_lambda_01/
      - zip -r9 ../my_lambda_01.zip .
      - cd ..
      - cd my_lambda_02/
      - zip -r9 ../my_lambda_02.zip .
      - cd ..
      - cd my_lambda_03/
      - zip -r9 ../my_lambda_03.zip .
      ...
      - cd my_lambda_09/
      - zip -r9 ../my_lambda_09.zip .
      - cd ..      

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Updating all lambda functions"
      - aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my_lambda_01 --zip-file fileb://my_lambda_01.zip
      - aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my_lambda_02 --zip-file fileb://my_lambda_02.zip
      - aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my_lambda_03 --zip-file fileb://my_lambda_03.zip
      ...
      - aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my_lambda_09 --zip-file fileb://my_lambda_09.zip
      - echo "Done"
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is that one of your lambda archives is too big.  350198 bytes seems sort of low though and doesn't seem to match up with the advertised limits.

AWS limits the size of direct uploads in the request so it may be better to try and upload to S3 first and then run the `update-function-code`.  Doing this should allow you to have an archive up to 250MB.

```
 - aws s3 cp my_lambda_01.zip s3://my-deployment-bucket/my_lambda_01.zip
 - aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my_lambda_01  --s3-bucket my-deployment-bucket --s3-key my_lambda_01.zip
```

Another option would be to try and reduce your archive size.  What types of data or libraries are you trying to use?   Make sure you aren't including extraneous files in your lambda archives (virtual environments files, temp build files, tests and test data, etc).  Can some things be offloaded to S3 and loaded into memory/disk at runtime?

If what you are trying actually needs to be very large, you'll need to package it up as docker image.  That was released a few months ago at re:invent 2020 and supports docker images up to 10 GB.

References:

- https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/packaging-aws-lambda-functions-as-container-images
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/optimizing-lambda-functions-packaged-as-container-images/